# Highchart how to use custom javascript variable in highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am trying to use custom current time variable but the variable value is not loaded from the data value of highchart.

I would like to generate the current time value as a variable and enter it into the highchart.

I've done a lot of searches but I can not seem to find an answer.
Please help me

+all problem is resolved. above code is complete code.
jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2qhmhh1c/1/

image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOPyP.png)

```
var ctime = new Date();

Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: 'areaspline',
plotBackgroundImage: 'http://www.khoa.go.kr/swtc/inc/img/chart/background.jpg',
width: 700
},
title: {
text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
},
xAxis: {
plotLines: [{
    color: 'white',
    width: 3,
    value: Date.now(), // <-- i want variable input in here!
    dashStyle: 'solid',
    zIndex: 4,
    label: {
    text: 'nowTime',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    align: 'center',
    rotation: 0,
    style: {
            color: '#000',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    }
}],
type: 'datetime',
tickInterval: 3600 * 3000,
min: Date.UTC(2017,5,1),
max: Date.UTC(2017,5,3),
tickWidth: 0,
gridLineWidth: 1,
gridLineDashStyle: "ShortDot",
gridLineColor: "#c1c2c3",
startOnTick: true
},
yAxis: {
tickInterval: 100,
title: {
    text: '(cm)',
    align: 'high',
    offset: 15,
    rotation: 0,
    y: -10
},
tickWidth: 0,
gridLineWidth: 1,
gridLineDashStyle: "ShortDot",
gridLineColor: "#c1c2c3",
startOnTick: true
},
tooltip: {
enabled: false
},
credits: {
enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
areaspline: {
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}
},
legend: {
enabled: false
},
series: [{
data: [
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 1, 00, 00),
        y: 586,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, 
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 2, 4, 18),
        y: 211,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.khoa.go.kr/swtc/inc/img/chart/graph_down.png)'
        }
    }, 
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 2, 10, 48),
        y: 744,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.khoa.go.kr/swtc/inc/img/chart/graph_up.png)'
        }
    },
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 2, 17, 13),
        y: 244,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.khoa.go.kr/swtc/inc/img/chart/graph_down.png)'
        }
    },
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 2, 23, 17),
        y: 668,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.khoa.go.kr/swtc/inc/img/chart/graph_up.png)'
        }
    },
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 3, 2, 17),
        y: 200,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.khoa.go.kr/swtc/inc/img/chart/graph_up.png)'
        }
    }
]
}]
});
```

Comment: Isnt ctime already a variable ? What you want is seeing it change over time right ?

Comment: So, what happens when you run that code? What is the output of your `ctime` variable, and what is the output of your `Date.UTC(ctime)` call? Provide a working fiddle for best results.

Comment: @Nevosis yes you're right i want seeing it change over time and ctime is variable. but It not be loaded in a highchart.

Comment: The vertical graph moves every minute on the graph via the "ctime" variable. And I will make a fiddle. @jlbriggs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a string out of your date elements.

The `Date.UTC()` function requires three separate arguments - you are only sending one, as a string. As a result, the function is returning `NaN` (*ALWAYS check the content of your variables when you're having problems, it almost always tells you what you're doing wrong*).

You need to pass the year, the month, and the day, as separate parameters. Try it this way:

```
Date.UTC(ctime.getFullYear(), (ctime.getMonth() + 1), ctime.getDate())
```

instead.

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2qhmhh1c/

Also - why are you adding a month to the date? It sounds like you're trying to plot data for the current date range, but you're plotting for a month in the future instead.

EDit:

It seems from updated post/comments that you're looking to plot the current date and time with the `plotLine`. In that case, you can just use `Date.now()`.

But, this will make it important to have the correct month in your data points - by adding `1` to your months, you are plotting in July instead of June (in javascript, month numbers start at 0, so `5` is June, `6` is July, etc.)

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2qhmhh1c/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will remember to your advice. Thank you very much^^

Comment: @KarmyDevel - see updated answer for better way to get the current date/time value